# Embed view controller inside container view based on selection from tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicontainerview

I'm trying to change the content of my container view based on what has been chosen from `TableViewController` and I'm out of an idea.

The structure in my `storyboard` looks like this:

[image: structure]

Currently, my container view has embed segue with Table View and that's working great. Now after select something from Table View for example Map I want to display `MapViewController` inside container view and keep my header and footer. How can I do this?

Comment: You will have to add manually the child viewController using the examples in the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First disable the segue form your container view to a `DestinationViewController` in your storyboard. 
Now load your viewController object based on your previous tableViewController selection.

```
//this controller will be change on tableView selection make your own logic here.
let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second")
addChildViewController(controller)
//Set this value false if you want to set Autolayout programmatically or set it true if you want to handle it with `frame`
controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: Thank you, can you explain to me where to put that instruction? Im also having problem with this "this controller will be change on tableView selection make your own logic here." can you explain to me how can I pass my selected record from TableView to change the controller ?